# How to generate a random polygon centered in Java?

Tags: java, polygon

I want to generate some randoms polygon but  I want it to be more or less centered in the middle of the given window coordinates.

Here is my code, it generates a random polygon but most of the time it's on the bottom of the window and I'd like to have it a bit more centered:

```java
    private static final double CORNER_MARGIN = 100.0; // max offset for a corner of the field, to randomize the polygon
    private static double[] standardPolygon(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
                                        // minX      maxX         minY      maxY --> it's the coordinate of the window
        double centerX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
        double centerY = (y1 + y2) / 2;

        // this is a standard polygon "centered" in the middle of the program window
        return new double[]{
                x1 -  (x2 - x1) * RANDOM.nextDouble(),  y2 + (y2 - y1) *RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN,
                x2 +  (x2 - x1) * RANDOM.nextDouble(),  y2 + (y2 - y1) *RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN,
                x2 +  (x2 - x1) * RANDOM.nextDouble(),  y1 - (y2 - y1) *RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN,
                x1 -  (x2 - x1) * RANDOM.nextDouble(),  y1 - (y2 - y1) *RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN,
        };

        /*return new double[]{
                x1 - RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN, y2 + RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN, // up left
                x2 + RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN, y2 + RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN, // up right
                x2 + RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN, y1 - RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN, // down right
                x1 - RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN, y1 - RANDOM.nextDouble() * CORNER_MARGIN, // down left
        };*/
    }
```

The code in comment is working but now I tried to center it but I only get some rectangles/squares. How can I manage to keep random polygon forms but a bit more centered ?

[EDIT] 
Here is how I draw the area of the polygon :

````java
    private void drawZone(Group group, IGameParameters gameParameters) {
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        double[] points = gameParameters.dronePadDeliveryZonePolygon();

        List<Double> pointsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (double point : points) pointsList.add(point);

        polygon.getPoints().addAll(pointsList);
        polygon.setFill(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE);
        group.getChildren().add(polygon);
    }```
````

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how you're drawing the polygon. But I'd specify in the function an origin for the polygon and base all vertex coordinates relative to that origin.  In your case, you'd calculate the center of the window and define that the origin.

You're randomizing the distance of the points from the center, which will give the appearance of it not being centered in the window. You'll need to offset the coordinates by the overall dimensions of the polygon.

Comment: look the edit for how I draw it

Comment: @Phaelaxz I calculated the center in X and Y, I'm not really sure about the "randomizing the distance of the points from the center" how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculated the center but don't use it anywhere.  Just so I understand correctly, this is a 4-sided polygon only and the corners randomly positioned at most 100 from the corner of the window?

I'm not 100% sure on how you want the polygon to be shaped but give this a try. Logically it works in my head, but I don't have a way to test the code right now.

```
private static final double CORNER_MARGIN = 100.0; 
private static double[] standardPolygon(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {

    double centerX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    double centerY = (y1 + y2) / 2;


    // Get the corner offsets
    ox1 = x1 + CORNER_MARGIN * RANDOM.nextDouble(); // top left
    oy1 = y1 + CORNER_MARGIN * RANDOM.nextDouble();

    ox2 = x2 - CORNER_MARGIN * RANDOM.nextDouble(); // top right
    oy2 = y1 + CORNER_MARGIN * RANDOM.nextDouble();

    ox3 = x1 + CORNER_MARGIN * RANDOM.nextDouble(); // bottom left
    oy3 = y2 - CORNER_MARGIN * RANDOM.nextDouble();

    ox4 = x2 - CORNER_MARGIN * RANDOM.nextDouble(); // bottom right
    oy4 = y2 - CORNER_MARGIN * RANDOM.nextDouble();


    // Calculate the center of the polygon
    double cx = (ox2 - ox1) / 2;
    double cy = (oy2 - oy1) / 2;

    // difference between window's center and polygon
    double offsetX = centerX - cx;
    double offsetY = centerY - cy;

    // offset the calculated points so the polygon's center matches the window
    ox1 += offsetX;
    oy1 += offsetY;
    ox2 += offsetX;
    oy2 += offsetY;
    ox3 += offsetX;
    oy3 += offsetY;
    ox4 += offsetX;
    oy4 += offsetY;

    // this is a standard polygon "centered" in the middle of the program window
    return new double[]{
            ox1, oy1,
            ox2, oy2,
            ox3, oy3,
            ox4, oy4
    };


}
```

Comment: Yes now I get the idea I'll work on it since it's not doing exactly what I want but I should be able do to the changes thank you